# Installed Vue.js wrong?

Tags: javascript, macos, vue.js, terminal

So I just started using vue.js and I normally use these commands to create a new project:

```
vue init webpack projectname
```

**In every youtube video this command works perfectly!**

**but somehow not for me? I'm getting the message:**

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied
```

If i type:

```
sudo vue init webpack projectname
```

it works perfectly.

**But** if I want to create a new file in my project directory, it always asks me for my admin password - even if I copy a file to another directory -  and that kinda sucks.

**Is there something wrong with my access rights?**

(I'm using the latest version of macOS)

**Or does it have to do something with vue?**

Do you guys have the same issue?

Comment: How did you install the vue CLI?

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions this might help

Comment: I used this tutorial to install vue CLI: https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/vue-js-2-quickstart-tutorial-2017-246195cfbdd2 I just simply used the `npm install -g vue-cli command`

Comment: I just tried 'brew doctor' and I got this message: 
_Warning: The following directories are not writable:
/usr/local/include

This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed
by Homebrew. If a formula tries to write a file to this directory, the
install will fail during the link step.

You should change the ownership of these directories to your account.
  sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/include_ @MattShirley

Comment: Have you checked out this GitHub issue? https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/194 - It appears to be extremely similar to your issue.